# Validate form through <a> tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am currently working with jquery validation and forms. I came across a great plugin [HERE](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) which so far works perfectly. I am running into a wall since I have a form split into sections inside jquery tabs. I have placed in these tabs `<a>` tags that act as buttons `Next` and `Previous`. Instead of clicking `submit` to validate, I would like to validate the fields when clicking  `Next` or `Provious`.  I have tried binding  to on click validate but I get no result. How can I validate the form by clicking on an `<a>` tag? Here is a mockup [Example](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/TabsNextPrev/)

```
//jquery tabs- Next and Previous
<script>
    $(function() {

        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

        $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){

          var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

          if (i != totalSize) {
              next = i + 2;
              $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
          }

          if (i != 0) {
              prev = i;
              $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
          }

        });

        $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
               $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
               return false;
           });


    });
</script>

//Jquery Validation
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
        jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
    });

    function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
        if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
            // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
            return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
        }
    }
</script>

//Jquery Bind <a> to validate 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("form").validate();
     $("a").bind("click", function() { alert($("form").valid()); });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
            <form id="formID" class="formular" method="post">
            <span>Name:</span><br>
            <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req" id="req" />    
            <label>
                <span>Favorite sport 2:</span>
                <select name="sport2" id="sport2" multiple class="validate[required]">
                    <option value="">Choose a sport</option>
                    <option value="option1">Tennis</option>
                    <option value="option2">Football</option>
                    <option value="option3">Golf</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            </form>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dynamically adding `<a>` tags so you'll need to use <strike>[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)</strike> [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) *(live is deprecated, thanks jbabey)*, as opposed to `bind`.

That way, any matching elements now or added in future will be properly bound.

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9, `.on()` is the preferred function for binding handlers.

Comment: Ah I missed that notice on the API page doh. Edited.

Comment: +1 I wasnt aware of that either. I follow your answer and used `.on()` but when leaving the fields empty and clicking `<a>` it doesnt validate anything.

Answer (score 0):

As `.live()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()` as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".next-tab, .prev-tab", function(() { 
           $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
           return false;
       });
```